# Google Analytics filter Dev, Acc, Prod?

Tags: google-analytics

Working on a project with 3 environements: Development, Acceptance and production.
dev.mydomain.com acc.mydomain.com and mydomain.com (currently beta.mydomain.com)

The same Google Analytics ID is present in the 3 environements.

I would like to track the analytics separately on the Production environement.

What is the best aproach for achieving this? Can I use a filter for a particular subdomain or should I make a new "property" in the analytics account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest different "views" with domain filters. You say all three sites have the same id, so you are set up for a view based approach in any case (different properties would give you different Analytics IDs).

With a "view" (what used to be called "profiles") based approach you cannot only test your website; you can also test new Google Analytics filters and if they work well in staging you can simply copy them to the live view. Also properties suggest fundamentally different data (like a web site and a mobile app) which is not the case with staging and live sites.

There is a predefined hostname filter in the view settings - which strangely enough has never worked for me, so I use a custom exclude filter based on the hostname (filter pattern is a regexp so properply escape special characters - i.e. subdomain.maindomain.com with an escaped dot).

Comment: Thanks! For me it was an option to generate a new ID just for the production site. But I prefer your suggestion.
I've just set up a hostname filter with "include only" - "traffic to the hostname" - "that are equal to" beta.mydomain.com
It is not working yet but I suppose it takes some time as the environement is brand new

Comment: Charlie, it might take up to 24 hours before the numbers appear.